# Eclipse PHP Incorrect Color Formatting / Highlighting

Tags: php, eclipse, syntax-highlighting

Sometimes my code color syntax formatting is off on some of my php files. In my case nearly everything is the same color except for keywords. This seems to be random and there are no apparent errors in my code. I'm thinking perhaps there is a small bug somewhere causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found at least one quick fix.

Simply make a copy of the php file, delete the original, then rename the copy to the original name. When you open/close and re-open the new file, the color syntax highlighting seems to magically fix itself.

If anybody knows what might be causing this in the first place please post your thoughts.